# LoadLibrary return 193 on newest version of Visual C++ on x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a problem with LoadLibrary (load dll library), problem occur after migration from Visual C++ 2008 to Visual C++ 2012.

When I try to use LoadLibrary on my dll I have an error (GetLastError return 193), which is strange because in old visual there is no problem with the same dll (x64 on both visual is set).

Comment: VIsual C++ 2012 is not the newest version; 2013 was until a week ago, when 2015 was released. So 2012 is actually two versions behind.

Comment: My mistake I have 2013, so I am one version behind.

Comment: It is a pretty plain error, stop assuming it has anything to do with the VS version.  It gets not so plain when it is *another* DLL with the wrong bitness that the DLL you are loading has a dependency on.  Otherwise basic DLL Hell.  Don't use Depends, it produces way too many false warnings.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see your program loading the DLL and searching for dependent DLLs, locating the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`, which means that the DLL you're trying to load, or one of its dependencies, is not a valid executable, or possibly a 32-bit executable. So you probably have some misconfiguration in your build.

You can use a tool like [Dependency Viewer](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the executables to see if they match.

Edit: Here's the description for 14001:

//

```
// MessageId: ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX
//
// MessageText:
//
// The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
// configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event
// log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
//
#define ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX        14001L
```

So it definitely appears to be a DLL dependency issue.

Comment: Ok but I try to load dll which was built on the old version of Visual (2008) in the new version of Visual (2013) and LoadLibrary return 193, when I build dll in the Visual 2013 LoadLibrary return 14001.

After use dependency walker, there is Error opening file
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL

but in the old dll there is the same problem and dll is correctly loaded on old version.